# Is it possible to capture the click on element present under Jquery div data-role="collapsible"

Tags: jquery

I have got two elemnts of   div data-role="collapsible" 
When clicked on the Edit Button , how to capture it without expanding the data-role="collapsible"?

This is my code

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">
    <div class="myactivelabelsWrap">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
            <h3>Heading 1<a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon">Edit</a></h3>
            <ul data-role="listview" class="labellistUL">
                <li class="labellist">
                    <div class="leftlable">
                        <p>Content here</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
            <h3>Heading 2<a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon">Edit</a></h3>
            <ul data-role="listview" class="labellistUL">
                <li class="labellist">
                    <div class="leftlable">
                        <p>Content here</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).on('click', '.labelEditIcon', function(event) {
      alert('clciked on edit');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/3/

Please let me know how to capture the click event on the Edit button ??

Comment: Why on earth are you delegating event if not required???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/tdzfhzjy/4/

**JS:-**

```
$('.labelEditIcon').on('click', function (event) {
    alert('clciked on edit');
});
```

Comment: @Kiran Please accept my answer if this works for you.

Comment: What if delegation is required? If OP doesn't need to delegate event then his question doesn't really make sense

Comment: @A.Wolff Looks like delegation is not working because the default on click event is preventing event bubbling.

Comment: @wizkid can i prevent it from collasable expanding  in this case ??

Comment: @wizkid Ya, then he should use capturing but really sounds like he just need to bind event ;)

Comment: @Kiran And to handle dynamic elements (as your question was suggesting it), you should **capture** event: http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/10/

Comment: @wizkid even if it won't prevent bubbling, you wouldn't be able to prevent the collapsing/expanding with a delegated event (in the bubbling phase) in that case as jQuery mobile directly attaches the handler to `[data-role="collapsible"]` therefore you would at least need to use `[data-role="collapsible"]`  as root of the delegate, which is nearly the same directly binding it  to `.labelEditIcon`

Comment: @A.Wolff I am going to use this for Jquery Mobile devices , so is that okay for jqm js ??

Comment: @Kiran Sorry, i don't know jqm js but there is no reason it wouldn't work, just that you should be aware than capturing phase isn't supported on IE<9. That's said, why not bind event directly to element as in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

here is code for you

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".labelEditIcon" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
alert( "The mouse cursor is at (" +
event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY +
")" );

event.stopPropagation();//this will stop collasable from expanding
});
});
```

JsFiddle updated code : http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/8/

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
$("div[data-role='collapsible']")
```